# Heroku error 'Couldn't find that process type (web)'

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I faced with problem. When I deployed my project on heroku and wrote this command in cmd, I get this error. Thanks in advance!

```
(base) MacBook-Pro-:fr_scraper $ heroku ps:scale web=1
 ▸    Couldn't find that process type (web).
```

Comment: what's in the contents of your Procfile?

Comment: @RyanBaker web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi --log-file -